# How can i get status code of a link that i embedded in my html

Tags: html

I have a basic HTML like this.

```
<p><a href="https://target_link" target="_blank"><b>some link</b></a>
```

How can I get the return status code of the link that has been provided. i.e whether the link is able to be accessible. The link pertains to an application hosted.

Comment: Sorry my html didn't show. The code is <p><a href="https://..." target="_blank"><b>some link</b></a>

Comment: you mean status code 200?

Comment: Yeah 200, 404,etc anything just to differentiate whether the page is accessible.

Comment: you cannot get the status code without the help of javascript.

Comment: Yeah im willing to use js, just dont know how to retrive it. Any sample codes will be really helpful

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use javascript for getting status code
       <script>
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url='https://target_link';
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();
        Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
          console.log(Http.status)
        }
      </script>
```